# Both side calendar sync

Tags: calendar, synchronization, caldav

I'm trying to make both sync calendar from my CMS. I'd like to do something like this:

In my iPhone I will add calendar feed from my CMS system and:
- if I create event in CMS, the event will be visible in CMS and also in my iPhone
- if I edit event in CMS, the changes will be visible also in my iPhone
- if I create event in iPhone in synced calendar, event will be visible also in CMS
- id I edit event in iPhone, the changes will be visible also in CMS

Is possible to make it via CalDav? Do you have any tips?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible via CalDAV. This is a good introduction on how all this fits together: [Building a CalDAV client](http://sabre.io/dav/building-a-caldav-client/).

Please ask more specific questions for more specific answers :-) [StackOverflow: How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just need to find out, if there is any way, how to make it. 
Thank you once :)